# Tailwind CSS set columns and rows dynamically

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I save images with their width and height. Using TailwindCSS I would now like to dynamically set the column or row width within a map function. However, this only works partially, because as you can see in the picture, the two upper right pictures have space downwards. But this should be filled out. How do I do it?

```
<div className="grid grid-flow-row-dense grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-4 lg:grid-cols-5 gap-2">
    <DocumentList results={results}></DocumentList>
</div>
```

DocumentList.tsx:

```
export const DocumentList = ({ results }: { results: any })=> {

...

  return (
    <div
      key={_id}
      className={`${
        height > width ? "row-span-2 " : width > height ? "col-span-2 " : ""
      }`}
    >
      <SingleItem coverImage={coverImage}></SingleItem>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]